# Can´t import "ApplicationsRequestBuilder" method in python using Azure SDK

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sdk-python

Following the official documentation, to list app registrations que must use "ApplicationsRequestBuilder", but there is no info about how to import it.

My imports are:

```
import pyodbc
import adal
import struct
import json  
import subprocess 
import asyncio 
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.models.password_credential import PasswordCredential
from msgraph.generated.applications.item.add_password.add_password_post_request_body import AddPasswordPostRequestBody
```

I´ve tried everything, but I´m not able to import it. The error is:

```
File "/azp/_work/1/s/Update_Expired_Service_Principals/sp_renewal.py", line 83, in get_sp_id
query_params = ApplicationsRequestBuilder.ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
NameError: name 'ApplicationsRequestBuilder' is not defined
```

My code is:

```
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']   
conn, credential, credentials = get_token()

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes=scopes)
    
async def get_sp_id():
    query_params = ApplicationsRequestBuilder.ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = "displayName eq 'test'",
        count = True,
        top = 1,
    )

request_configuration = ApplicationsRequestBuilder.ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
    query_parameters = query_params,
)
request_configuration.headers.add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")

app_list = await graph_client.applications.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
if app_list:
    app = app_list[0]
    sp_id = await graph_client.applications.by_application_id(app.id).get()
    print(sp_id)
    return sp_id
return None
```

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement is to list app registrations using azure python sdk like [this](https://i.imgur.com/qVcbHu6.png)?

Comment: Yes. In this case, the goal is to retrieve the objectID of a specific App Registration using its name. The issue is that there are many App Registrations, and when we use the "get application", we can´t see all the App Registrations.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TA7zKJA , this is my function

Comment: Could you please add that code by editing your question in code format not as image?

Comment: yes, sure! Now it´s done

Comment: I fixed it just using the "import" that I wrote on this post

Comment: God bless your for asking this question. It answered my question about a mistake in docs.

The docs said that the password request body model should be imported like this:

`from msgraph.generated.models.add_password_post_request_body import AddPasswordPostRequestBody`

But in fact, it should be imported as your code shows:

`from msgraph.generated.applications.item.add_password.add_password_post_request_body import AddPasswordPostRequestBody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error is required to add:

```
from msgraph.generated.applications.applications_request_builder import ApplicationsRequestBuilder
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have below app registrations with display name as **'test'** :

[image]

To get **objectID** of these app registrations, you can make use of below sample Python code:

```py
import asyncio
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

client = GraphServiceClient(credential)

async def main():
    target_app = "test"

    result = await client.applications.get()
    applications = result.value

    filtered_applications = [app for app in applications if app.display_name == target_app]

    for app in filtered_applications:
        print(app.id)

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Response:**

[image]